# i want to split string by Square brackets using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

data = "[json][17:50 timestamp] hello [mike18][18:06 timestamp] hi"
print( re.split("\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\][^a-zA-Z0-9_]", data) )
```

The result I expected is:

```
["[json][17:50 timestamp] hello", "[mike18][18:06 timestamp] hi"]
```

But the real result is:

```
['', 'json', '17:50 timestamp', 'hello ', 'mike18', '18:06 timestamp', 'hi']
```

What regular expression should I use?

Comment: Well, if you are OK with your pattern logic, try `re.findall(r"(?:\[[^][]*]){2}[^][]*", data)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` instead with a pattern that matches any number of square-bracket-enclosed sequences followed by a sequence of non-square-bracket characters. Use a positive lookahead pattern to ensure that it is followed by either another square bracket or the end of the string:

```
re.findall(r'\s*((?:\[.*?\])*\s*[^[]+?)(?=\s*\[|$)', data)
```

This returns:

```
['[json][17:50 timestamp] hello', '[mike18][18:06 timestamp] hi']
```

Note that with the positive lookahead pattern you would be able to avoid matching a trailing space, which @WiktorStribiżew's solution in the comment would include but your expected output does not.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another one could be a lookaround:

```
(?<=\s)(?=\[)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LLOU45/1).